# OneDrive huge streaming upload

Tags: http, onedrive

I'd like to upload a stream of unknown length larger then 100 MBytes to OneDrive. The API endpoint I use is [Resumable item upload](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_large_files.htm). My question now is if there is a possibility to set the `Content-Range` header to a value which enables the transfer of a stream with unknown size.

As [RFC7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.2) states in section 4.2 `Content-Range: bytes 42-1233/*` would state that the total length is unknown, but unfortunately that fails with a HTTP 400 with the body`{"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"Invalid Content-Range header value"}}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, when uploading via chunks OneDrive must know the expected length in order to intelligently commit the upload when it is complete. If you feel that being able to upload an unknown amount of data feel free to submit an idea [at our uservoice site](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/category/89523-developer) - be sure to outline your scenario.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. Very sad, all the competitors can do that. Imagine encrypting a file and putting it to OneDrive or Video Encoding